# How to change Control+ Dot (ShowSmartTag) in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tags, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the code snippets `Cntrl + .` -> `"Create and assign Property.."`.

At present its generated as shown below code.
Where do I change the code so that the property can be auto-created with "_" and camelcasing like `"_db"`.

```
        public UserRepository(ApplicationDBContext db)
        {
            Db = db;
        }

        public ApplicationDBContext Db { get; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try: Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#=>Code Style=>Naming=>Click on Manage Naming Style, then click the plus sign in the lower left corner of the pop-up box=>Choose a name you want, and then in " Fill in "_" in "Required Prefix" => Select camel Case Name in "Capitalization". Then click Confirm. This naming convention is complete. Then return to the Naming interface and click "+" in the lower left corner, select the corresponding member variable to use this rule